# StarUML Class Diagram : How to manually add Generics (Template Type T) for a class

Tags: templates, generics, staruml

Below is the image to show a Generic class of **Type T** in the UML Class Diagram.

I could not figure out how to add the T Template Box on top of Generic Class (set in the Image) using Star UML.

Is there any way in Star UML to add this Generic Type T box on top of a Generic class?

For the Derived Classes of this Generic Base Class, I have already added `<<bind>>` stereotype with the types that they use.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm using version 2.7.0, and you can add `Template Parameter` to the target class to indicate Generics.

**Details**: After you add a `class` or an `interface`, right click the diagram, and then choose `Add`->`Template Parameter`. You can edit the template parameter(or generic type) at the top-right of your `class` or `interface`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding some details to the solution you provide?